# Flow: Auto Create 12 Month Child Records From Parent Employee Record Using Flow

Tags: workflow, process-builder, visual-workflow, create-records

Using Process Builder to call the flow on record create.
I have a Contractor object.  When a new Contractor is created, I need to auto create 12 (one per month) Time Sheet object records (regardless of what month or how many months left in the year, I still need 12 records created).
Each record will be for each month & has the Start & End of the Month (2 fields - both of which I can calculate using formulas).
Each new Time Sheet record will reference the Contractor (name & supervisor) directly from the parent record.
I looked into creating a single record using Process Builder & Cloning the record in flow, but couldn't figure out how to create the remaining 11 months.
I'm a flow novice so guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a loop counter which keeps count of number of records to create.

It will be similar to below flow

[image]

**Step1:** You create the process builder which calls the flow(contractor Id needs to be sent to the flow)

**Step2:** On the flow, You will lookup contractor id which was passed from process builder

**Step3:** Create a assignment variable and initializes it's value with 0

[image]
**Step4:** A decision logic block to see if assignment variable < 12

[image]
**Step5:** If true, create a new time sheet record.
[image]

**Step 6:** Increment the Loop counter

[image]